# C++ - How do you make Explicitly Imported DLL functions available to other classes

Tags: c++, dll

I have a dll called `mydll.dll`, in the dll there is a function called `testFunc()`. I would like to have `testFunc()` available in other scopes outside of the scope where it is `GetProcAddress()`'ed in.

For instance:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
typedef void(*f_testFunc)();
int main(){
    // load dll into hDll
    f_testFunc testFunc = (f_testFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "testFunc");

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        A a = A();
    }
}
```

**A.cpp**

```
class A{
    public:
    A(){
        testFunc();
    }
}
```

I simply want a way to use `testFunc()` anywhere in my code without having to re-grab it from the dll.

Comment: What about passing the function pointer around?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is there a way that I could include the function via header?

Comment: You can put the typedef for the function pointer in a header file, and use it elsewhere in your code. Classes that should call this function can be supplied with the function pointer (grabbed once), e.g. in their constructor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would it be possible to put several pointers of imported functions in a `struct`?

Comment: Of course that would be possible. You can also make a proxy wrapper class that does all of this internally (grabbing function pointers, etc.). Usually such stubs are automatically generated by the linker, when you build a shared library.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that kinda went over my head, can you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to make a sample for the [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437574/c-how-do-you-make-explicitly-imported-dll-functions-available-to-other-class#comment41519445_26437574) DLL wrapper class

```
 typedef void(*f_testFunc)();

 class DllWrapper {

      DllWrapper(HDLL hDll) {
          testFunc_ = (f_testFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "testFunc");
      }
      void testFunc() {
          (*testFunc_)();
      }

 private:
      f_testFunc testFunc_;
 };
```

---

```
 class A {
 public:
     A(DllWrapper& dll) dll_(dll) {
          dll_.testFunc();
     }

 private:
     DllWrapper& dll_;
 };
```

---

```
int main(){
    // load dll into hDll
    DllWrapper dll(hDll);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        A a = A(dll);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the benefits of using this way over the example using `extern` by CBHacking?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell It's more flexible, especially if you want to have more than one function from this DLL. Also global extern variables clutter your code, and make it harder to get what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a header file (myheader.h). Declare the function variable there, as extern. Include this header in all your source files. Explicitly define the variable and set it in main.

**myheader.h**

```
typedef void(*f_testFunc)();
extern f_testFunc testFunc;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "myheader.h"
f_testfunc testFunc;
int main () {
    testFunc = (f_testFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "testFunc");
    for (int i ...
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "myheader.h"
class A {
    public:
    A () {
        testFunc();
    }
}
```